# Replace string on given input

Tags: unix

I need to replace particular string based on country input which get passed to my bash script program

I am trying to change the existing code

```
table_value=$1
ctry_input=$2
final_var=$(echo ${table_value}| sed -e "s/\@ctry/${ctry_input}/")
```

Input values

```
if table_value=random_@ctry_final 
and ctry=KL
then final_var=random_KL_final
if table_value=source_@ctry_final
and ctry in (nz,uk,us)
then final_var=source_nz_final subsequently the string would be replaced for uk and us
if table_value=source_@ctry_final
and ctry in (aus,cn)
then final_var=diff_aus_final. In this case source_@ctry_final should be replaced as diff_aus_final. source string needs to be replaced as diff for countries under aus,cn
```

Is there a way to tweak the existing variable code instead of using if else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added quotes in `echo "${table_value}"`, that is not needed for the solution but is a good practice.
I use the `sed` option `-r` avoiding backslashes for special characters (option `-e` is not needed).
After the original code I added an additional command replacing a part when the string looks like `source_aus_` or `source_cn_`.

```
final_var=$(echo "${table_value}"| sed -r "s/\@ctry/${ctry_input}/;s/source_(aus|cn)_/diff_\1_/" )
```